# Using Unity to build this ios project, Added google signin SDK 4.0.1 Framework, I get error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I want google login in my app so i want to write unity plugin ,but i do not wanna use Play Games Unity plugin.

So I follow this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/).

But after I have added the framework,I get error message.

My tool version

1. Unity 5.6.0f3
2. Xcode 8.3.1
3. Google Sign-In SDK 4.0.1

Xcode Builld error message

```
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Users/user/unityWorkspace/GoodTest2/NOgpgs/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/user/unityWorkspace/GoodTest2/NOgpgs/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      ___70+[GTMSessionFetcher evaluateServerTrust:forRequest:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionFetcher_28beddf8a47a0abe7f4eaa9a5c9cb75b.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain removePasswordForService:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch saveParamsToKeychainForName:accessibility:authentication:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
      -[GIDSignIn randomString] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_5e9c07ce1f20710c59c1499209a8b99a.o)
  "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
      -[GIDSignIn randomString] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I googled about it , I found that it seems like something about arm64 support of Google Sign-In SDK.

I have set scripting backend on Unity to IL2CPP, and target architecture to Universa(both armv7 and arm64). 
Now I have no Idea to resolve these errors.

Comment: You can tryout https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/94517

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Missing Security.framework.
Now! It working.